# ¿Queda actualmente algún caso en el que el participio de presente se use como verbo?

Tags: gramática, verbos, dle, participio

Antiguamente el idioma español tenía dos tipos de participios: el participio pasivo o de pasado, que corresponde a la forma actual AMADO, y el participio activo o de presente, correspondiente a la forma AMANTE.

El DLE define el participio de presente así:

> **[participio de presente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S0EdlKH)**
>
> 1. m. Gram. Forma verbal procedente del participio de presente latino, con terminación en *-nte*, que en español se ha integrado casi por completo en la clase de los adjetivos o en la de los sustantivos.

Por ejemplo, la voz *[amante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2Dm6VRP)* hoy día es un sustantivo, y la voz *[correspondiente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Az1JeBU)* que he usado arriba hoy es un adjetivo.

Sin embargo, me intriga ese *casi* que ha usado la RAE en la definición. ¿Qué quiere decir la RAE con que el participio de presente se ha integrado **casi** por completo en la clase de los adjetivos o en la de los sustantivos? ¿Hay casos en los que se siga usando el participio de presente como tiempo verbal? Si es así, ¿son estos casos cotidianos o solo casos esporádicos de autores que tratan de [imitar el habla antigua](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27804/12637)? ¿O se refiere a que hay participios de presente que se han integrado en otras categorías aparte de los adjetivos y los sustantivos?

Comment: One of the things as a learner which always puzzled me is that Spanish uses the passive (past) one where I expected an active (present) one. Like _aburrido_ where I would have said boring. That does not seem to be mentioned in the quote you give.

Comment: @mdewey you're quite right. In Spanish you can say that something is _hiriente_ when it hurts you, but _aburrido_ (and not _aburriente_) when it bores you. Maybe you should ask a question about that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> en español se ha integrado casi por completo en la clase de los adjetivos o en la de los sustantivos

Sobre el "**casi**", me inclino por tu última alternativa: 
no es que hayan sobrevivido casos de este uso verbal (la Gramática española es bastante terminante: "no existen en el español actual participios de presente"), sino que **adjetivos** y **sustantivos** no agotan las asimilaciones.

Hay, en efecto, un par de **preposiciones** («durante», «mediante») y al menos un **adverbio** («bastante»).

---

Editado: descubro algunas cosas dignas de [notar](https://www.metro.pr/pr/blogs/2013/06/16/nuevas-preposiciones-espanol-durante-mediante-versus-via.html) sobre  «durante», «mediante» : sólo fueron aceptadas como preposiciones recientemente. Y es claro sólo esa función es compatible con el uso actual, en el cual no hay concordancia en número: decimos normalmente

«El hecho ocurrió durante los días de huelga»

y en cambio consideramos [incorrecto](https://www.lateja.cr/sucesos/estos-son-los-delitos-cometidos-durantes-los-dias/QWVAS4PWVNDS3F23JCXZTGAQMA/story/) escribir

«El hecho ocurrió **durantes** los días de huelga»

Sin embargo, esta segunda construcción era la usual hace unos tres siglos, y corresponde al uso original como participio. Y de hecho, informalmente [aún se usa](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22durantes%20las%22) (aunque a mí me suena fatal). Esto abre la posibilidad a otra respuesta sobre aquel "casi" de la cita original.
Más información [aquí](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/gramatica-gramatica-de-la-lengua-castellana-destinada-al-uso-de-los-americanos--0/html/ff6ef310-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_51.html) (donde citan ejemplos adicionales:  "(no) obstante"...)